# Cannot set up azure data factory V2 self hosted Integration runtime on my computer

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a laptop and need to set up a self hosted IR.
It won't let me set up IR.  The error is:

Error Code: 1004
Error: Microsoft Integration Runtime (Self-hosted) is already installed on this computer.
Suggestion: If you want to register the new Integration Runtime (Self-hosted) node on the same machine, uninstall the old Integration Runtime and retry the express setup from the Azure portal.

How do I find or list the old integration runtime to delete it?  Thanks!

Comment: Go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features` search for "Microsoft Integration Runtime" and uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks!  I also found out the install has a remove button that would remove it as well.